# Symfony - Installing FOSJsRoutingBundle (Compiler Error)

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I am trying to install FOSJsRoutingBundle. I followed the documentation [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/installation.html). But for some reason I get this error:

> Compile Error: Label 'not_fos_js_routing_js' already defined
>
> Stack Trace in var\cache\dev\FooUrlMatcherGenerator.php

```
> return $this->mergeDefaults(array_replace($matches, array('_route' => 'fos_js_routing_js', '_site' => '2')), array ( 
> '_controller' => 'fos_js_routing.controller:indexAction',  '_format'
> => 'js',));
>             }
> not_fos_js_routing_js:
```

I cleared all the caches in many ways (manually and with the command). I installed the assets ...etc but still same outcome.
rooting

```
fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"
```

layout (javascript block)

```
{% javascripts  '@fooBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'
                '@fooBundle/Resources/public/js/bootstrap.min.js'

%}
<script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}

<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' })
```

My javascript script where it is used:

```
var url= Routing.generate('foo_rout_that_exsists', { id: 3 }, true);
alert(url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

config.yml

```
fos_js_routing:
      routes_to_expose: [ "[a-zA-z0-9_-]+" ]
```

Your can also refer symfony offical document for [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/installation.html)

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I am still having the same error.

Comment: I cannot because it's private. But I can share here any parts of the code that may lead to this problem.

Comment: I think the problem is fos_js_routing_js is generated twice in the cache. But I am not sure why. None of my other routes have that.

Comment: No, I mean when I open the generate cache file (that re-generate if I clear the cache with the same error), I find that fos_js_routing_js_routing is part is defined twice. The other routes only once.

If I search using Find in Path, this route is not duplicated in my declarations.

Comment: I did that in various ways before, but still same thing. The source of the problem is not the cache, is what generate the cache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153219/discussion-between-robert-and-m20).